# Design Approach and Using Reflection to run methods in Java

Tags: java, reflection, process

I have a question. I have multiple classes in a package: Let's say package is

```
com.myPackage.first
```

And this package has the following classes:

```
firstGood
secondGood
thirdBad
fourthGood
```

Each of these classes have a method with the same name but different implementation. So say each have a one particular function called:

```
public void runMe(){

}
```

For now I want to come up with a way to given a class name, it'll go inside the class and run that particular method.

So conceptually, my method will look like those:

```
ArrayList<Class> classList ; // where classList is a list of classes I want to run 

public void execute(){
 for(Class c : classList){
  // Go inside that class, (maybe create an intance of that class) and run     the method called run me
 }
}
```

or

```
public void execute(Class c, String methodToRun){
 for(Class c : classList){
  // Go inside that class, (maybe create an intance of that class) and    run     the method called run me
 }
}
```

For now. what I have been able to do is get the name of the classes I want to run the

```
runMe()
```

method. So I have been able to come with a way to get the arraylist of classes I want to run. So what I need help with is coming up with a method such that it takes a class name and run the method I want it to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "For now I want to come up with a way to given a class name" what do you mean by class name? Do you mean its full name like `com.myPackage.first.firstGood` or just `firstGood`?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure which is better. In terms of design, do you think one approach is better. Also note that my work so far has been to return the class names not preceded by the package name. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3):

I suggest having a look at `Class.forName ( ... )` to get the class object, `Class.newInstance();` if your classes have a default constructor (or `Class.getDeclaredConstructor(...)` otherwise) to create a new instance and then `Class.getDeclaredMethod( ... )` to find the method and invoke it.

All of this without any regard if your idea is really a good one, since I really didn't quite understand WHY you want to do what you want to do...

Answer (score 3):

```
interface Me {
    void runMe();
}
```

Then let all classes implement Me.

And have a list of `Me`s

```
List<Class<Me>> ...
```

Then

```
void test(Class<Me> cl) {
    Me me = cl.newInstance();
    me.runMe();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Going the interface route

Answer (score 2):

My adage is always *use reflection to solve a problem - now you have two problems*. In view of that have you considered a simple pattern like this:

```
interface Runner {

    public void runMe();
}

static abstract class BaseRunner implements Runner {

    public BaseRunner() {
        // Automagically register all runners in the RunThem class.
        RunThem.runners.add(this);
    }

}

class FirstGood extends BaseRunner implements Runner {

    @Override
    public void runMe() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":runMe");
    }

}

class SecondGood extends BaseRunner implements Runner {

    @Override
    public void runMe() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":runMe");
    }

}

static class RunThem {

    static final Set<Runner> runners = new HashSet<>();

    static void runThem() {
        for (Runner r : runners) {
            r.runMe();
        }
    }
}

public void test() {
    Runner f = new FirstGood();
    Runner s = new SecondGood();
    RunThem.runThem();
}
```

Here all of your `runMe` objects extend a base class whose constructor installs the object in a `Set` held by the class that calls their `runMe` methods.

Answer (score 1):

inline

```
void execute() throws Exception{
    for (Class<?> c : classesList)
    {
        //If you don't already have an instance then you need one 
        //note if the method is static no need for any existing instance.
        Object obj = Class.forName(c.getName());
        // name of the method and list of arguments to pass
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName,null);
        //method accessibility check
        if(!m.isAccessible()) 
            m.setAccessible(true);
        //invoke method if method with arguements then pass them as new Object[]{arg0...} instead of null  
        //if method is static then m.innvoke(null,null)
        m.invoke(obj, null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an Interface that defines the runMe() method and then have all your classes implement that interface. Then you would have a list of this Interface:

```
List<MyInterface> classes = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
```

Then you could easily iterate over it and invoke "runMe()" on all of them or if you only want to invoke it for instances of a certain class you could do it like this:

```
public void execute(Class classForWhichToExecute) {
    for (MyInterface myInterface : classes) {
        if (classForWhichToExecute.isAssignableForm(myInterface)) {
            myInterface.runMe();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this wouldn't work if your method is a static method - so adding more information from your side would help.

Comment: That method is not static. For now, I have taken the advice of creating an interface and having  runMe() in it so the classed can implement that method. Can you pls elaborate on this statement "Then you would have a list of this Interface" thanks

Comment: Sure, instead of having a List of Class objects, you would now have a List of instances of objects, all implementing your new interface. Since any class implementing your interface has to implement the method you can simply invoke the method without having to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use an interface with a common method to override in each class. So that any class can be casted to interface and use its method to execute the method.

```
interface GoodAndBad{
    public void runMe();
}
```

Implemented class

```
class FirstGood implements GoodAndBad{
    @override
    public void runMe(){
       // Code to be executed
    }
}
```

You can use `execute()` method as follows

```
public void execute(List<GoodAndBad> classList){
    for(GoodAndBad c : classList){
        c.runMe();
     // Go inside that class, (maybe create an intance of that class) and  
       //  run the method called run me
    }
}
```

Change the `Class` to `GoodAndBad` interface to change the other method too.

This is loosely coupling objects to support favor over composition in Java Object Oriented Design Patterns.

Never use Strings of method names to execute a method at anytime. There are plenty of other cool solutions for that using design patterns.